# Referencing webjar from sass in playframework

Tags: scala, playframework, sass

In order to reference a webjar from a sass file in playframework, the [documentation](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.6.x/AssetsSass#Mixing-Sass-and-web-jars) is very clear:

> sbt-web will automatically extract WebJars into a lib directory
>   relative to your asset’s target directory. Therefore to use the
>   [as an example] Compass mixins you can import the mixins by:
>
> `@import "lib/compass-mixins/lib/compass";`

However I can't make it work for me when trying to use `material-design-web`.

The dependencies in `build.sbt`:

```
  "org.webjars.npm" % "material-components-web" % "0.43.0" excludeAll(
    ExclusionRule("org.webjars.npm", "material__image-list"),
    ExclusionRule("org.webjars.npm", "material__icon-toggle"),
    ExclusionRule("org.webjars.npm", "material__dom"),
    ExclusionRule("org.webjars.npm", "material__typography"),
    ExclusionRule("org.webjars.npm", "material__shape"),
    ExclusionRule("org.webjars.npm", "material__linear-progress"),
    ExclusionRule("org.webjars.npm", "material__floating-label"),
    ExclusionRule("org.webjars.npm", "material__dialog"),
    ExclusionRule("org.webjars.npm", "material__menu")
  )
```

Then in `login.scss` I put what I believe is the correct value `@import "lib/material-components-web/material-components-web";` and get the error:

```
Error: File to import not found or unreadable: lib/material-components-web/material-components-web.
       Parent style sheet: /Users/jem/projects/personal/lux/app/assets/stylesheets/login.scss
        on line 2 of app/assets/stylesheets/login.scss
>> @import "lib/material-components-web/material-components-web";
   ^
```

I have tried many variations, including:

```
@import "lib/material-components-web";
@import "material-components-web/material-components-web";
@import "material-components-web";
@import "../material-components-web";
@import "../material-components-web/material-components-web";
@import "../lib/material-components-web";
@import "../lib/material-components-web/material-components-web";
@import "../../lib/material-components-web";
```

etc, but can't find the correct path.

According to the documentation, `@import "lib/material-components-web/material-components-web";` should be correct. Looking at the compiled files, `@import "../material-components-web/material-components-web";` should be correct. Neither work.

Comment: I was sucessful with "lib/material-components-web/material-components-web". But then it failed to resolve the dependencies starting with "@material/<component>"

Comment: Yes, I see. I created an MCVE and I get the same thing. https://github.com/Synesso/play-mdc-sass-mvce

Comment: let me know when you find out how to make it work.